# Reading Floating Point values in VB.NET does not give expected values

Tags: vb.net, floating-point, readprocessmemory

```
Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Integer, ByVal lpBaseAddress As Integer, ByRef lpBuffer As Integer, ByVal nSize As Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Integer) As Integer '--- Should anyone of these be single instead?

        Dim p = Process.GetProcessesByName("insert random process name here")
        If p.Count > 0 Then

                Dim ReadBuffer As Integer = 0 '--- Should this one be single instead?
                ReadProcessMemory(p(0).Handle, &H400000, ReadBuffer, 4, 0)

                Dim Result As Single = ReadBuffer
                Msgbox(Result.ToString)

        End If
```

I could be using `integer` in the wrong places and should probably use `single` but when I do I still don't get the correct values. For example, I've changed the `ReadBuffer` data type to `Single`. The error could also lie here: `Declare Function ReadProcessMemory` on one or several of the `Integer's`.

This is an example value I expect to get: `16.6317005` and the value I do get instead is: `-9,808334E+08`, or `1,1471E-25` or something else, all depending on where I change the `integer` data type to `single`. I never get the correct value and I've tried all combinations.

Or is it perhaps just a conversion issue?

So I guess my main question is - What's wrong with my code? How do I properly read Floating Point values in VB.NET?

Comment: What makes you think that what you're reading would a) be a Single; b) be able to be grabbed by reading an integer; and c) have the value you expect from reading the memory of *random app process*?

Comment: A) I know for sure that it's a Floating Point value though. Is Single in VB not the right data type for Floating Point values? B) As mentioned, I've also replaced Integers with Single. C) I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: It's weird that you can read anything: this is the declaration: `<DllImport("kernel32.dll")> Public Shared Function ReadProcessMemory(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, <Out()> ByVal lpBuffer As Byte(), ByVal dwSize as Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead as Integer) As Boolean
End Function`. You haven't answered to Ken White's point `b)`, that's the most intriguing.

Comment: Wrong *point*: I mean the `C)` point, related to this: Dim p = `Process.GetProcessesByName("random app process name here")`. It appears that you're sure to get a float value from a memory address of a random process.

Comment: Okay, both of you have misunderstood my "random process" text... I'm not reading from a random process, I just wrote that in the example. I know which process I'm reading from and I am sure that it's a floating point value. The focus is shifting away from the main issue now.

Comment: I've replaced the Integers to Single on the following: ReadBuffer, lpBuffer, lpNumberOfBytesWritten. Including the ending of the declaration line, this one: "As Integer" to "As Single". Still wrong value received...

Comment: Use the Function's declaration that I posted. Then [BitConverter.ToSingle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tosingle)

Comment: It's handling bytes and booleans, how will that help?

Comment: `lpBuffer` is a byte array: `dim result as single = BitConverter.ToSingle(lpBuffer, 0)`

Comment: Used your code and I don't get any value at all.

Comment: Here: 1F D2 84 41 58 9D D6 3E 6C 96... I think you're missing the point though, the example value is not really important.

Comment: FTR, I didn't *misunderstand* anything. When you write *random process*, it means *random process*, because we can't read your mind or see your screen to know you mean something other than *random process*. If you don't want people to *misunderstand* what you write, then write what you actually mean instead of something else. :-)